# Modeling a low poly tree

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine, edit-mode

I've been modeling a low poly tree and i was wondering if i could add a branch to the tree without having to subdivide the tree a lot of times, thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: **Quick tip**: to make snapshots of blender interface press Ctrl F3

Comment: PrtSc (top row of the keyboard, to the right of the alphanumeric block) will also do in a pinch.

Comment: Cant you add it as separate geometry?

Answer (score 11):

You can use inset (<kbd>I</kbd>) to create the base of the branch. That way you can avoid having ngons.

[image]